# Remove item from list if in another list (lists of list)

Tags: python

I have a list that looks like this

```
a = [('Eth1', 'desc', 'date'), ('Eth2', 'dest', 'date'), ('Eth3', 'dest', 'date')]
```

I have another list that has this:

```
b = = ['Eth1', 'Eth2']
```

I want to remove all occurrences of b in a with its corresponding data, so at the minute I have

```
c = list(set(a) - set(b))
print c
```

I want c to look like this

```
c = ['Eth3', 'dest', 'date']
```

But it just prints the list in a different order, like this

```
[('Eth2', 'dest', 'date'), ('Eth1', 'desc', 'date'), ('Eth3', 'dest', 'date')]
```

What would the best way to do this be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a list comprehension:

```
In [4]: [tup for tup in a if tup[0] not in b]
Out[4]: [('Eth3', 'dest', 'date')]
```

Note that you can't use `set`'s operations here because you don't want to compare the tuples entirely but the first items (then removing the whole tuple based on it).

Also if you're lists are longer you better to use a `set` for preserving the `b`'s items. The reason is that the membership checking is O(1) in sets.

For the sake of completeness here is a functional solution too (not recommended in this case, specially if you want the result to be a list):

```
In [7]: list(filter(lambda x: x[0] not in b, a))
Out[7]: [('Eth3', 'dest', 'date')]
```

Comment: If `b` is long in the real code, consider making a set out of it first. For the O(1) lookup, as you know.

Comment: @timgeb I was about to add that;)

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it using the `filter` function:

```
a = [('Eth1', 'desc', 'date'), ('Eth2', 'dest', 'date'), ('Eth3', 'dest', 'date')]
b = ['Eth1', 'Eth2']

res = list(filter(lambda i: i[0] not in b, a))
print(res)
```

Output:

```
[('Eth3', 'dest', 'date')]
```